# How to return from python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first programming practice. I have a python function like this:

```
sum = 0
def summation(a,b):
    sum = a+b
    return sum
```

and when I call function as

```
summation(3,4)
```

It does not return anything. Why?

Comment: Your function is returning. What is more likely is that you are not printing the result. Try `print(summation(3, 4))` to see your result.

Comment: You need to send the result of the function to `stdout` if you want to see the result. So what @ColinRicardo

Comment: if you want the result of the function stored in a variable then do the following `sumthing = summation(3, 4)` your result will be stored in `sumthing`

Comment: I hope you are aware that your "inner" `sum` and your outer `sum`live in different scopes - they are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum = 10               # this is a variable called sum 
print(id(sum))         # prints a unique ID for the sum object

def summation(a,b): # this is a function with its own scope 
    sum = a+b          # this is a different variable also called sum
    print(id(sum))     # prints unique ID for the inner sum object
    return sum

sum = summation(1,3)  # now your 1st sum object is overwritten and holds the result of 3+4

print(sum)
```

Output:

```
139971258264288 # unique id of the 1st sum variable
139971258264096 # thats the id of the other sum variable inside    def summation(a,b): ...
4   # and thats the result of the addition stored into the 1st sum variable
```

Read more about scopes here: [Scope or resolution-of-names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) it is one of the earlier pyhon beginner errors.  And when you are at it, also read and follow:  [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

```
def summation(a,b):
    sum = a+b
    return sum


sum1 = summation(3,4)
print(sum1)
>> 7


sum2 = summation(10,10)
print(sum2)
>> 20
```